# Delegates to "anonymous" interface proxy

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, castle, enterprise-library-5, objectbuilder

May be you know if  the standard .net framework library / ms enterprise library contains something like this functionality:

```
IConvertible proxy = CodegenThatEverybodyNeed.CreateProxy<IConvertible>(
         new Func<TypeCode> {...}, 
         new Func<IFormatProvider,bool>{...} , ...
);
```

I'm petty sure that this task ("anonymous proxy") is common and it is clear that it is possible to have a run time realization, but do not imagine where I could meet this function...

P.S. Of course it is better to have design time realization with type checks, but I have no doubts  this is impossible right now.
P.P.S. "Well known" freeware libraries are also welcome.

**ObejectBuilder**
It seems that ObjectBuilder should have this functionality but 15 minutes was not enough to understand how to learn it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647453.aspx

May be somebody have nice sample?

**EntLib Interceptions** Also this code should be somewhere int Unit.Interceptions but I do not found how reuse it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately for my goals (to avoid customers panic) castle is too big (panic will be even stronger than after Emit end code generation on the fly). Need something from more "standard" source.

Comment: what do you mean by 'too big'? the size of the DLL?

Comment: provided functionality is too large.

Comment: by that measure, the .NET framework is also 'too large'. you don't have to use the bits you don't want. just use the bits you do want.

Comment: .NET Framework is already accepted by my customer as EntLib and some other extensions...

Comment: So what is the issue with Castle? Are they unwilling to let you use a feature from Castle which you need just because Castle can also do other things which you don't need?

Comment: Somebody should prepare materials for review. Ok I've decided to push castle. :) At least it is better documented then ObjectBuilder

Comment: Good luck - sounds like you have rather an awkward customer ;-)

Comment: No, no... :) My customers are best customer in the world :)